# Docker run tomcat image without port mapping

Tags: tomcat, docker

I've just installed Docker on Windows 10 and I am trying to run a tomcat image without port mapping using this command:

```
$ docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.0
```

As [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) on dockerhub says, it can be run and be accessible via `http://container-ip:8080`in my browser, but sadly, I am not able to connect to it even thought I checked my container's ip via `$ docker inspect <container-id>` command.

Why am I not able to connect to tomcat without port mapping?

Answer (score -1):

You are using host browser to access it which is not possible without port mapping. What they are trying to say is, by running this command

```
$ docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.0
```

you should be able to access tomcat by using the browser inside the container (not the host browser).
To access it on the host browser you must use port mapping.

Comment: That's not true. The host machine can access the container IP directly. The issue here is that the *host* is a virtualized Linux (docker-for-windows) over a Windows machine.

Comment: @Robert that is true, it works on Linux, but not on Windows. Could you explain why (or provide some articles to read about differences between docker on windows and on linux)?